# Count formula in select msql - velocity

Tags: php, mysql, excel

can you help me to count a velocity by select to my SQL:
Velocity according this:

[image]

My database looks as follow:

[image]

MySQL select looks as follow:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM project_has_tasks WHERE project_id='10' GROUP BY milestone_id ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "" . $row["SUM(value)"]. ",";
    }
} 
$conn->close();
```

The results for project_id='10' looks like this:

50, 20, 15

Ok. this is simple, but is there any possibile to use the above velocity formula In mysql select Or somwhere else (PHP?)
So the results taking the formula:

[image]

Should looks like this:

50, 35, 28.3

Any help?

Comment: why don't you calculate it in php after u got the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't support CTEs, you can build a query for that in two steps. First you get the sum of the `values` for each `milestone`, with the query like the one you already wrote

```
SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value)
FROM    project_has_tasks
WHERE   project_id='10'
GROUP BY milestone_id
```

Then you join the query above with itself

```
select  t1.milestone_id, sum(t2.val) / count(t2.val)
from    (
            SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) val
            FROM    project_has_tasks
            WHERE   project_id='10'
            GROUP BY milestone_id
        ) t1
join    (
            SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) val
            FROM    project_has_tasks
            WHERE   project_id='10'
            GROUP BY milestone_id
        ) t2
on      t1.milestone_id <= t2.milestone_id
group by t1.milestone_id
order by t1.milestone_id desc
```

You can see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/ADA39876)

Comment: Ok Stefano, one thing more: is there any possible to count an avrage for each row exept first one?

For example I have these values like: 1/3/3/5/3 so the results as avrage of these should by like: 1/2/2.3/3/3

Comment: I think not the same:
http://rextester.com/HLCA7339

The results are: 3/3,5/3,6/4/3 and shoud be like: 1/2/2.3/3/3
Just according to the velocity column above :)

Comment: It's the same calculation, just in reverse order. You can get that result changing `<=` to `>=` in your rextester